# httpwebrequest Login Form

Tags: .net, vb.net, twitter, http-post, httpwebrequest

i followed all instructions of this tutorial and downlaod the code from this website: 
http://www.sourcecodester.com/visual-basic/5882/how-create-program-login-twitter-visual-basic.html

But try it ! i can't to be logged on twitter
why ?

Firstly problem ( resolved ), it was an error into the regex to get the token:
replace the .co.uk by  https://twitter.com/

Second problem ( resolved ), it was an error to do verification of the source code html.
replace "View my profile page" by "yourpseudo"

Third problem: can't be logged on twitter ( not resolved ) and this is the "why" i ask this question.

Try it. it doesn't work .. please help me guys.

THE CODE MODIFIED:

```html
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Form1
    Private Function GetBetween(ByVal Source As String, ByVal Str1 As String, ByVal Str2 As String, Optional ByVal Index As Integer = 0) As String
        Return Regex.Split(Regex.Split(Source, Str1)(Index + 1), Str2)(0)
    End Function
    Dim loginCookies As CookieContainer
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim token As String = getToken()
        Dim postData As String = "session%5Busername_or_email%5D=" & TextBox1.Text & "&session%5Bpassword%5D=" & TextBox2.Text & "&remember_me=1&return_to_ssl=false&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=%2F&authenticity_token=" & token
        Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
        Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
        Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
 
        Dim r As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create("https://twitter.com/sessions"), HttpWebRequest)
        r.KeepAlive = True
        r.Method = "POST"
        r.CookieContainer = tempCookies
        r.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        r.Referer = "https://twitter.com/"
        r.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36"
        r.ContentLength = byteData.Length
        Dim re As Stream = r.GetRequestStream()
        re.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
        re.Close()
        Dim res As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(r.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        tempCookies.Add(res.Cookies)
        loginCookies = tempCookies
        Dim src As String = New StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
    'replace this next line by your twitter username
        If (src.Contains("yourusernametwitter")) Then
            loginCookies = tempCookies
            MsgBox("Success!")
        Else
            tempCookies = Nothing
            MsgBox("Failed.")
        End If
    End Sub
 
    Private Function getToken()
        Dim r As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.twitter.com")
        Dim re As HttpWebResponse = r.GetResponse()
        Dim src As String = New StreamReader(re.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
        Return GetBetween(src, "<input type=""hidden"" name=""authenticity_token"" value=""", """")
    End Function
End Class
```